# How is $t\cos 2t = \sinh^2 3t?$

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve a Laplace transform problem for the function $f(t)=t\cos 2t$ and on the solution to this problem the author writes the function as $\sinh^2 3t$.

Why can the function be written in that way?

Comment: It can't. Something is incorrect. They is no equality.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you.

Comment: A simple way to spot this would be to pick $t$ such as $\pi/4$. Then $t\cos2t=0$, but $\sinh^23t$ clearly isn't $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Nope... that's not even close, as you can see here:

[image]